# Favicon not showing up when I am giving a path to a file in directory

Tags: html, path, favicon

like `href="logos/media/svg/logo.svg"`. When I am moving logo file to the folder where html file is -- it gets shown but when i add a path it not gets showed instead it shows default earth favicon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
href="/logos/media/svg/logo.svg"
```

or `href="../logos/media/svg/logo.svg"` if the html file path is /html/